# Can't access static methods from outside until JavaScript's static block is over?

Tags: javascript, static, static-block

```
class B {
    foo() {
        return A.foo(); // message: Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined
    }
}
class A {
    static {
        console.log(new B().foo());
    }

    static foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I expected the "foo" to be called, but I can't even access A class. Isn't the A class declared when the static block works?

Comment: This code works for me...

Comment: @vr. What browser did you use?

Comment: Chrome 102.0.5005.193, are you using a bundler or transpiler of some sort?

Comment: @vr. I am currently using Chrome 11.0.5563. The above code was executed on the console of the Chrome developer tool.

Comment: My bad, it does not work for me either. The tool I was using to run it was transpiling the code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks), static blocks...

> allow statements to be evaluated **during initialization**, which allows initializations that (for example) include try...catch or set multiple fields from a single value.

These blocks are evaluated during the initialization of the class, and therefore, the class is not initialized, nor is it defined yet; hence the error.

So in conclusion, the behavior you are seeing is expected. That also explains why moving the static block down (after the `foo` method) does not fix the error, and also why `this.foo()` works but `new B().foo()` does not,

```js
class B {
    foo() {
        return A.foo(); // message: Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined
    }
}

class A {
    static foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
    
    static {
        console.log(this.foo());    // ok
        console.log(new B().foo()); // errors
    }
}
```

... given this (also from MDN).

> Initialization is performed in the context of the current class declaration, with privileged access to private state.

Comment: Is it right not to determine that the class has been terminated until the static block ends?

Comment: @서다운 What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you determine that the A Class's declaration has been completed after the static block is over?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong translation.

Comment: No, while the block is being executed, A has not been declared yet.

Comment: Thank you completely understood